# DynamoDb scan filter not returning results for some requests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with two columns FirstId and SecondId. **FirstId is the primary key and SecondId is not indexed**.

```
FirstId |  SecondId    
--------------------
  abc   |  123     
  xyz   |  789
```

I'm doing a scan filter to get the FirstId value from the SecondId using the JavaSDK. I've around 12k entries and it was working fine. Recently, the scan request has started returning `null` for some cases, although, **I can find the entry in the AWS UI**.

Here is my code

```
    Condition scanFilterCondition = new Condition()
        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(secondIdValue));
    
    Map<String, Condition> conditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
    conditions.put("SecondId", scanFilterCondition);

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName(table)
            .withScanFilter(conditions);
    
    ScanResult result = mDBClient.scan(scanRequest);
    if(result.getItems().size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
        
    Map<String, AttributeValue> item = result.getItems().get(0);
    
    return item.get("FirstId").getS();
```

I'm assuming this might be due to the operation getting expensive as the data grows! Is there a way I can optimize this request? Or, is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Check your scan results to make sure they arent being paginated.  Scan can only return up to 1mb at a time.   If you are grabbing 1MB of values, filtering them all out, you'll get the behavior you are experiencing.  You may need to keep checking your DB for the next page using the ExclusiveStartKey of the first scan.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan Basically, my table is a one to one mapping and I'm expecting at most one result to be returned by the function. So do you think pagination is still going to be relevant in this case?

Comment: Could be, but it depends on the size of your data.  If the data you have in the sample is representative of your actual data, you probably don't have a pagination issue.  However, if your ID's are larger and/or you have other attributes, it's definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be explained by understanding how DynamoDB handles scans, filters and pagination.

A few things to remember:

- Each `scan` can only read up to 1MB of data at a time
- Filter operations are applied *after* the `scan` (or `query`)
- Scan will search the entire database

Taking these into consideration, it's possible you will have to paginate through several empty scan results before finding (or not finding) the data you are after.  You could be reading a full 1MB of data, filtering it all out, and returning an empty result set to the client.  `result.getItems().size()` may be zero, but that doesn't mean that you don't have to perform another `scan` operation to complete the search.

I'm not certain that this is your problem, but it's easy to verify.  DDB will return a field `LastEvaluatedKey` with your `scan` results *if* the `scan` operation is being paginated.  If so, you'll need to make another `scan` request to continue the `scan` operation.

Again, this may not be your problem, but it could explain why you aren't seeing the results you expect from a single `scan` operation.

Comment: I tried this one too. Still, it was not returning the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I had a long debugging session with the AWS support engineers and still, we could not figure out the reason. AWS CLI and UI both were returning the result, but not the JAVA SDK scan query.

So, I created a GSI for `SecondId` and changed my code to do index-query rather than a scan query, and it fixed the problem for me.

```
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(table);
    Index index = table.getIndex("SecondId-index");

    QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("SecondId = :second_id")
            .withValueMap( new ValueMap()
                .withString(":second_id", secondIdValue));

    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = index.query(spec);

    if(!items.iterator().hasNext()) {
        return null;
    }
    
    JsonNode result = jsonMapper.readTree(items.iterator().next().toJSON());

    return result.get("FirstId").asText();
```